# How to differentiate and club together multiple select dropdowns?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

I have a table with multiple rows, and 4 columns. Each column contains a select dropdown, the options in the second column depends on the selection of first one, third one depends on second one and so on. I tried giving ids to selects and implementing onclick listeners. but it works only for the first row. Please help me solve this.

Here's the HTML code:`

```
<table>
{% for int i in (0,x) %}
<tr>
<td>
<select id='Product'>
<option>Car</option>
<option>Bike</option>
<option>Bus</option>
</td>
<td>
<select id='Model'>
</td>
<td>
<select id='Make'>
</td>
<td>
<select id='Color'>
</td>
</tr>
{% endfor%}
```

Here's the Jquery:

```
$("#product").change(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var val = $(this).val();
                if( val == "none"){
                        $('#Model').empty().append($("<option></option>")
                                        .attr("value","none")
                                        .text("Select"));
                        $('#Make').empty().append($("<option></option>")
                                        .attr("value","none")
                                        .text("Select"));
                        $('#Color').val("Red");
                }else{
                        var url_select = "/XYZ/product/?selected_product=" + val;
                        $(".innerload").css("visibility", "visible");
                        $.get(url_select, function(data){                      
                              $('#Model').empty().append($("<option></option>")
                                                .attr("value","none")
                                                .text("Select"));
                              $('#Make').empty().append($("<option></option>")
                                                .attr("value","none")
                                                .text("Select"));
                                $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                                        $('#Model')
                                                .append($("<option></option>")
                                                .attr("value",item.model)
                                                .text(item.model));
                                });
                        });
                }
 });
```

Similar jqueries for Model and Make onChange.

Comment: bomb us with your js script

Answer (score 0):

Please do not use same id in multiple time in loop id same for all time that's way it's not work

Comment: I used class instead, but it changes all the column select options in all the rows.

Comment: you can use loop variable with id so it will different for all select

Comment: How will I handle on clicks if I use different ids?